# MVC4, Render Partial View in Dialog Box with jQuery, How to refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, jquery-ui-dialog

I have a partial view that is popping up in a dialog with the code below. However, after the user saves the partial view the data does not refresh in that partial view when I click the ActionLink again until I stop debugging and restart the app. However, the new record is in my databsae. The other issue is when I restart the app I cannot update the record because of the error below. What am I missing? Thanks.

```
    An object with the same key already exists in the ObjectStateManager. The ObjectStateManager cannot track multiple objects with the same key.
```

The div tag in my View

```
    <div id="assign-dialog"></div>
```

The ActionLink in the same view

```
    @Html.ActionLink("Assign", "Edit", "Assignment", new { id = Model.InfoId}, new { @class = "assign-modal" })
```

The jQuery

```
    $(function () {

$(function () {
    $('#assign-dialog').dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        width: 400,
        height: 500,
        resizable: true,
        modal: true
    });

    $('.assign-modal').click(function () {
        $('#assign-dialog').load(this.href, function () {
            $(this).dialog('open');
        });
        return false;
    });
```

});

The HTTP GET action

```
    [HttpGet]
    [Authorize(Roles="Admin")]
    public ActionResult ViewAssignment(int id = 0)
    {
            RequestAssignment query = _assignmentRepository.GetCurrentAssignment(id);

            return PartialView("_ViewAssignment", query)
    }
```

UPDATE:

I originally followed the steps in [javascript/jquery modal popup dialog MVC 4 / render partial view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16577011/javascript-jquery-modal-popup-dialog-mvc-4-render-partial-view) under the dynamic section of Jasen's answer, but did not know what to put in the "Client Partial, empty for now "

...okay so going off some other posts I have read this is what I was able to come up with, but nothing happens when I click my link.

View html

```
    <a href="#" class="dialog-trigger" data-infoId="@Model.InfoId">Assign</a>
    <div id="assign-modal">

    </div>
```

jQuery

```
    //Dialog Box for Assignments
 $(".dialog-trigger").on("click", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var infoId= $(this).data("infoId");
    $.ajax({
        url: "RequestAssignment/Edit/" + infoId,
        type: "GET"
    })
    .done(function(result) {
        $("#assign-modal").html(result).dialog("open");
    });
});
```

Comment: I always refresh my partials with an ajax call.  look at my answer here for an example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19643864/how-do-i-render-a-partial-form-element-using-ajax/19643974#19643974

Comment: thanks. I think that is where I am getting stuck. I looked over dozens of posts and could not figure how to make it dynamic because it is going to bring up an Edit View based on an ID. I think the issue was I could not get the ID to pass from the View to the jQuery. I originally had an ordnially <a href> tag with a data-Id attribute, which I thought passed the variable. I looked over this dynamic example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16577011/javascript-jquery-modal-popup-dialog-mvc-4-render-partial-view and was not having any success

Comment: if you do use an ajax call there is a data parameter that you can set with the id that you want to send to the view.  As long as the variable in the data matches exactly the input parameter on the controller it will be passed

Comment: let me try that and I will post my code

Comment: I was able to step through some of the jQuery and the variable is passing correctly, but the view is still not popping up so I must be missing something else

Comment: an ajax call doesn't redirect for you.  I noticed your controller has a redirect to action on it.  If you want to redirect you either need to post back (where you controller would be correct), return a partial on your controller (will be returned through the ajax call - see my link above), or send success and do a window.location to redirect from your javascript

Comment: okay, sorry I think I confused myself last night when I was posting this. The click even on the link is an HttpGet Action. I updated my controller action and the jQuery in my post.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46440/discussion-between-matt-bodily-and-jay-michael)

Answer (score 0):

so after some long searching, I decided to use Ajax.ActionLink. I know there are better ways out there, but this one was working for me. I want to thank @MattBodily for all the help along the way.

```
    @Ajax.ActionLink("Approve", "QuickAssign", "Assignment", new { id = Model.InfoId}, new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "GET", UpdateTargetId = "result", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, OnSuccess = "openDialog" })
```

then my javascript function

```
function openDialog() {

     //set the diaglog properties
     $("#result").dialog({
         title: 'Assign',
         width: 550,
         height: 'auto',
         modal: true
     });


     $("#result").dialog("open");
}
```