# How to dispaly a view in a popup

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, popup

Like i have said in the title, what i want to do is that : display a view in a popup when i click on a link!
i have already shown some text on the popup, but i don't now how to display a view in the popup!
Code:

```html
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Create popup</h2>
<input  onclick="showPopup()" type="button" value="Click"/>
<div id="divContaiPopup" class="table-responsive" style="display:none;">
    <div>
        <table class="table table-striped table-hover3">
            <tr>
                <td>hi</td>
                <td>hello</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function showPopup() {
        $("#divContaiPopup").dialog({
            height:400,
            width:500,
            modal:true,
            buttons:{
                "OK":function(){
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                    aert('you selected ok!!')
                },
                "Cancel":function(){
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                }
            }
        }
        );
                }
    
</script>
```

Scripts:

```html
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.20.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**:

```
function showPopup() {
            $(document).ready(function() {
                    $("#divContaiPopup").dialog({
                        height:400,
                        width:500,
                        modal:true,
                        buttons:{
                            "OK":function(){
                                $(this).dialog("close");
                                aert('you selected ok!!')
                            },
                            "Cancel":function(){
                                $(this).dialog("close");
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    );
            });
        }
```

Scripts:-

```
<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

**Or**

Check this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16577011/javascript-jquery-modal-popup-dialog-mvc-4-render-partial-view)

Comment: Thanks for replying me, i have already done this and it works but my problem is how to show a "view" (MVC) in a popup by calling an action in a controller, not just a content of a 'div' that exists in the same page!